# Reading from csv adds whitespace that can't be removed Java

Tags: java, csv

I am reading from a csv file of people, starting with their id, name, and date they joined the application. When reading the first row, the first index adds a whitespace to the string. I am unable to remove this whitespace, as I want to parse it to an integer.

```
File nameOfFile = fileName;

    BufferedReader br = null;
    String line = "";
    String cvsSplitBy = ",";

    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nameOfFile));
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            String[] row = line.split(cvsSplitBy);

            temp = row[0].trim();
            temp.replaceAll("^\\s", "");
        //     temp.replaceAll(" ", "");
       //     String.format("%03d", temp);

            System.out.println(temp.length() + " " + temp + " "  + temp.charAt(0));

            age = Integer.parseInt(temp);

            name = row[1];
            dateJoined = row[2];



        }

    } catch (FileNotFoundException | ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {

        System.out.println("File is not found, please try again.");
        System.out.println(exception);

    }

    if (br != null) {
        br.close(); //close buffered reader
    }
```

My csv file:

4   John    10/10/2010

5   Charles 24/08/2010

6   Andrew  09/01/2011

The System.out.println(temp.length() + " " + temp + " "  + temp.charAt(0)); prints this:

2 4

1 5 5

1 6 6

where this    System.out.println(temp.length() + " " + temp + " " + temp.charAt(1)); prints out:

2 4 4

Comment: `String` doesn't have a method named `Trim`. Please post valid compilable Java code. --- What's with the `j` tag?

Comment: `println(temp.length() + " " + temp + " " + temp.charAt(1))` cannot print `1 6`, because if `temp.length()` is truly 1, then `temp.charAt(1)` would throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: yeah it does post that but I am using it for testing purposes.

Comment: `temp.replaceAll("^\\s", "");` has absolutely no effect. Strings (such as `temp`) are immutable. Read the Javadoc on `replaceAll` to find out what it does.

Comment: The expression `row[0].trim()` should have removed the space, if it was a space. The fact it hasn't suggests that it's not really a space. Could it be a Byte Order Mark instead? How are you saving your CSV file? As Unicode?

Comment: @whome4321 But you're stating a falsehood. That `println` statement cannot print that output, because exception happens before the statement prints *anything*. Please show *actual* code and *actual* output from that code. Don't make it up.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou ah okay I was wondering that but still no luck. and I am saving it as a CSV UTF-8.

Comment: @Andreas It actually prints out the first 2 4 4 then throws the exception

Comment: What you're showing for _"My csv file"_ has no commas in it; checking the edit, it has _tabs_ between fields ("tsv") so your code + data cannot work as you are saying it does. As has been said, post your _actual_ code and data.
CSV is also far more complicated than just `,` between fields, and there are Java CSV parsers already freely available - I'd recommend using one.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou You was right! I checked the csv file on notepad++ encoding tab and the file was saved at UTF BOM. I changed it to UTF and it works, thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent the wheel. I would use the Univocity parser and then map. 
More info at: https://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-documentation
Something along this (did not test it);

```
CsvParserSettings settings = new CsvParserSettings();
CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(settings);
List<String[]> allRows = parser.parseAll(new FileReader(yourfile));
List<Person> persons = allRows.stream().map(p->new Person(p[0],p[1],p[2])).collect(Collectors.toList())
```

In the Person bean I would make specific setMethods, such as:

```
public void setAge(String age2parse){
try{
this.age = Integer.parse(age2parse.replaceAll("[^\\d.]",""))
}catch(Exception e){
}
}
public void setName(String name2parse){
this.name = name; // You could divide name here, if wanted.
}
public void setDate(String date2parse){
this.date = date2parse // I would parse it and store it as Date object.
}
```

Finnaly, a constructor in the bean;

```
public Person(String a, String n, String d){
setAge(a);
setName(n);
setDate(d);
}
```

To print:

```
persons.stream().forEachOrdered(p->System.out.println(p.getAge()+" "+p.getName()+" "+p.getDate()))
```

Note: There is even way to use BeanRowProcessors, which seem to fit well when you have more fields in the bean, so please, check the documentation on Univocity.